# Is it possible to use alias for keys in yaml with symfony/yaml?

Tags: symfony, cakephp, yaml

I've been trying to read the following yaml file using symfony/yaml(v4.4.0) with cakephp3.
But, I get the following error.

```
Reference "aaa" does not exist in "path to yml" at line xx (near "*aaa:").
Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException
```

I would like to user the 'aaa' as a key later.
It doesn't work with "*aaa:" and works with "1:".
Basically, is it possible to use alias for keys in yaml file?

Here's the yaml file.

```
aaa: &aaa 1
bbb: &bbb 2
ccc: &ccc 3

*aaa: # <- this doesn't work and works with '1:'
  - *bbb
  - *ccc
```

Comment: For the future, please give the actual error message instead of just saying „it doesn't work“.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've added details.

Comment: This is a bug in Symfony's YAML parser and you will need to file an issue with them to get it fixed. Not much we can do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For general spec-conforming YAML parsers**

You need to write it with a space before `:`.

```yaml
aaa: &aaa 1
bbb: &bbb 2
ccc: &ccc 3

*aaa :
  - *bbb
  - *ccc
```

YAML 1.2 allows `:` to be part of an anchor and therefore, the line will not be parsed as implicit key if `:` is written adjacent to the alias (since it becomes part of the alias then).
This has been [discussed on the YAML core mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/yaml/mailman/message/34909032/).

**For Symfony**

It seems Symfony parses `*aaa:` as alias `*aaa` with `:` as value indicator. While this is a spec violation, it shouldn't bother us since according to the mailing list, this is more like an oversight in the spec. However, Symfony fails to resolve the alias here, there's nothing much you can do about it but to file an issue for it.

Comment: Then your question is not about YAML, but about a bug in a specific implementation. This code is valid YAML, as can be checked online with [PyYAML](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) or [NimYAML](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) (my work).

Comment: I'm sorry for not to write the detail first. It seems a bug of symfony/yaml..